# Several compiled plans for query in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

We have a procedure in SQL Server 2012 with a query like this:

```
    SET @sSQL = 'SELECT Column1,
                        Column2
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE Column1 = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @ColumnID )
```

@ColumnID is an inparameter in the stored procedure.

It creates a lot of Compiled plans. Why and how can we solve it?

Comment: Show your entire stored procedure, why do you use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sp_executesql` so the value can be a parameter:

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT Column1,
                    Column2
             FROM   Table
             WHERE  Column1 = @ColumnId';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@ColumnId int', @ColumnId = @ColumnId;
```

Comment: Why `INT` and not `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER/DATE`?

Comment: We do use EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL already. But is it the convert that is the issue?

Comment: @Star . . . The point is to use parameters and not embed them in the string.  Among other things, this allows the SQL engine to compile the query only once.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Because the working code has no single quotes surrounding the value, suggesting it is numeric.

Comment: In addition to the lack of quotes, due to the implicit length of 32 for `NVARCHAR` when used in `CONVERT` without a length a GUID would cause an overflow error, e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, NEWID())`. So while it is not certain `ColumnID` represents an integer it is a pretty good guess. It is also a pretty good reason to [never declare, or convert to varchar/nvarchar without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @GarethD, the default length in the `CONVERT` function is 30 rather than 32.

Comment: @DanGuzman Urghhh, Clumsy fingers and poor proof reading to blame there.... You are of course correct. Well spotted.